# undefined references SDL with Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, sdl, undefined

I was following http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/codeblocks/index.php tutorial on how to use SDL with Code::Blocks since I've been having trouble with this in pretty much every damn IDE I've tried.

The tutorial is pretty straight forward, on step number 7 it states
"we have to tell the compiler to link against the libraries. Go under Linker Settings and paste -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2". I did exactly that. Then it says that if you get a bunch of undefined reference errors, you messed up this step, I don't really see how it is possible for me to mess up this step, since it is a simple step.

I would really like to get started with this, while using MinGW and Code::Blocks.
Information that might help resolve this:

1. I have MinGW directory located in my C:
2. I have a folder SDL in my C: directory, within that folder I am linking the include and lib files from SDL to Code::BLocks by right clicking on project properties and adding the directories. This all seems to be working fine.Include Directory = C:\SDL\SDL2-2.0.3\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2 Lib Directory = C:\SDL\SDL2-2.0.3\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib
3. As stated above, on the Linker Setting -> Other Linker Options: I wrote -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2, yet I get a bunch of reference errors. I don't know what to try, I have been searching online for hours, I even replaced SDL_platform.h because it was causing issues and the undefined references are still there.

Please help. This is the code I am using to check if SDL is working, it isn't.

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <Windows.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Fire up SDL, this starts all subsystems; audio video etc.

    if ( SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to init SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(1);
    }
    // Now Shut it down
    atexit(SDL_Quit);

    return 0;
}
```

These are the errors I am getting:

-------------- Build: Debug in TITLE (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

```
mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -g -IC:\SDL\SDL2-2.0.3\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2 -c C:\Users\Bryan\Desktop\CodeBlocks\TITLE\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
mingw32-g++.exe -LC:\SDL\SDL2-2.0.3\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib -o bin\Debug\TITLE.exe obj\Debug\main.o  -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2  
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `SDL_main':
C:/Users/Bryan/Desktop/CodeBlocks/TITLE/main.cpp:10: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
C:/Users/Bryan/Desktop/CodeBlocks/TITLE/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
C:/Users/Bryan/Desktop/CodeBlocks/TITLE/main.cpp:15: undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a(main.o): In function `main':
e:\p\giaw\src\pkg\mingwrt-4.0.3-1-mingw32-src\bld/../mingwrt-4.0.3-1-mingw32-src/src/libcrt/crt/main.c:91: undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
4 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a Windows executable project. The wizard set the entry point to `WinMain`. Your code implements a command line program with `main(int argc, char**argv)` as entry point.

If you want to stay with the `main` you should create a new *command line* project and add you 
source files to this project. Alternativly you could try to change the project type.

For the SDL errors you should check, that you use matching compiler and libraries (32 vs. 64 bit).

Comment: Thank you, I had my compiler and libraries mixed up, not only that, I also didn't have the libraries within MinGW. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Here is an answer that worked for me.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303032/unable-to-successfully-link-to-sdl2-libs-i-get-undefined-reference-for-all-sdl?rq=1